# Google Apps ScriptでTwitterAPIを利用し、ツイートへのリプライ送信について

Tags: google-apps-script, twitter

Twitterで@返信されたとき、Google Apps Scriptから@返信されたツイート元にリプライを送りたいのですがよく分からないです
in_reply_to_status_idを使うのかなと思ったのですが、どのように記述すればいいのか分からないんです…
「みりあやんないよbot」さんみたいな感じで返信したいのですが…
リソースに、TwitterWebService(バージョン2)とOauth1(バージョン16)を入れてます
初心者の僕に教えてください！！！！

【追記】ツイート部分をGASではこのように打ってみました

```
value["in_reply_to_status_id"] = value["id_str"];
    var status2 = value["in_reply_to_status_id"] + "\n@"+value['user']['screen_name'] + "\nこの返信はテストです。\nご迷惑おかけします。";
    var replyTo2 = value.in_reply_to_status_id;
    Twitter.tweet(status2,replyTo2);
    Logger.log("返信先: %s \n返信内容: %s",replyTo2,status2);
```

GASのログではこのように出力されました(~は省略してます)

[18-11-24 12:19:47:220 JST] 返信先: 10661~24448
返信内容: 10661~24448
@wata~
この返信はテストです。
ご迷惑おかけします。

ツイッターでは

10661~24448
@wata~
この返信はテストです。
ご迷惑おかけします。

でした
ツイートIDを指定して、そのツイートに対するリプライを行いたいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Twitter.tweet` は提示されている2つのライブラリには含まれていないかと思いますが、 もしかして https://webird-programming.tech/archives/274 にあるTwitter.gsでしょうか？

もしそうであれば質問のコード自体には問題ないようにも見えますが、Twitter.gsの方にミスがありそうです。

当該コードの277行目あたり、

```
  if (reply) {
    if("string" === typeof reply) {
      data.in_reply_to_status_id_str = reply;
    } else {
      data.in_reply_to_status_id = reply;
    }
  }
```

となっていますが、文字列か数値かによる分岐は不要で

```
  if (reply) {
    data.in_reply_to_status_id = reply;
  }
```

とすれば求める挙動が実現できそうな気がします。(試したわけではありません)

---

p.s. 使用したコード・ライブラリや参考記事、質問コードにおける変数定義箇所などは漏れなく記載しておいてもらえると回答しやすくなります

Answer (score 1):

自己回答はこんな感じで書けばいいのかな？

**回答ありがとうございました！！**
わざわざ回答していただいたのに申し訳ないですが、自己解決しましたので報告させていただきますm(__)m

```
var option = {
    "status":"@"+value['user']['screen_name']+"\nこの返信はテストです。\nご迷惑おかけします。",
    "in_reply_to_status_id":value.id_str
    }
    Twitter.api("statuses/update",option);
```

で解決しました
**https://webird-programming.tech/archives/274 のTwitter.gsを使用しています**、記入していなくて申し訳ございませんでした
一番最初に回答していただいたhinaloe様の回答をベストアンサーとさせていただきます